# Command present in two locations and both locations are in PATH

Tags: linux, path

I have this situation in which the same command/program (eg: myScript) is present in two locations, `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin`. Both these locations are in the PATH.

When I run

```
$ myScript
```

1. How do I know from which location myScript will be picked up?
2. Can I force the use of one of the locations (without having to delete myScript from one of the locations)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `myScript` will be picked up from the FIRST location it is mentioned in the `PATH` variable.  You can test this using `which myScript` (it should return the location first seen in `PATH`).
2. Use absolute or relative addressing to call the script directly.  Instead of `myScript`, try `/path/to/myScript` referring to the one you wish to use in your code.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Do you think it would be a good idea to add an alias like:
alias myScript '/path/to/myScript'?

Comment: It's a matter of preference, I guess.  Adding an alias is another way to go about it.  Best practice would be to alias the script only, and not alias command line inputs to the script.

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/  Observe that the questioner has asked a generic question.